# OpenShift - Cannot Build dockerfiles from private bitbucket repo

Tags: dockerfile, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I'm trying to create a application from a dockerfile in my Private Bitbucket repo, when I go through the web console to make it I've tried using both the SSH and HTTP url's and the ssl/user+pass secrets but its not detecting the Dockerfile in my repo.

I've also tried using the CLI to create it both on Windows and Ubuntu...

```
oc new-app git@bitbucket.org:mitch-user/myapp.git --context-dir src --source-secret bitbucketssl --strategy docker --name myapp
```

but I get the following

```
warning: Cannot check if git requires authentication.
W1126 11:17:56.680242   31748 dockerimagelookup.go:300] container image remote registry lookup failed: you may not have access to the container image "docker.io/library/base:latest"
error: only a partial match was found for "base": "openshift/jenkins-agent-base:latest"

The argument "base" only partially matched the following container image, OpenShift image stream, or template:

* Image stream "jenkins-agent-base" (tag "latest") in project "openshift"
  Use --image-stream="openshift/jenkins-agent-base:latest" to specify this image or template
```

Has anyone seen this issue before? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you using "base" somewhere in your codebase?

Comment: Can you paste your dockerfile? it seems the image you're trying to use just doesn't exist.